# Within a loop logic to write CSV file - Spark DF, Equal Splits

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv

I work with local Hadoop Spark instance.
I have code the code below that splits my spark df into 4 parts.
I would like each part to be written to CSV during the process (i.e. file 1, file 2 ..4)
I know I can use `df.toPandas().to_csv('file1.csv')` but I'm not sure how I get 4 separate files.

Why? Because of memory issues on my laptop. I am getting java errors when exporting whole file. If I export 10% of the data it's ok.

```
# Define the number of splits you want
n_splits = 4
  
# Calculate count of each dataframe rows
each_len = df.count() // n_splits
  
# Create a copy of original dataframe
copy_df = df
  
# Iterate for each dataframe
i = 0
while i < n_splits:
  
    # Get the top `each_len` number of rows
    temp_df = copy_df.limit(each_len)
  
    # Truncate the `copy_df` to remove
    # the contents fetched for `temp_df`
    copy_df = copy_df.subtract(temp_df)
  
    # View the dataframe
    temp_df.show(truncate=False)
  
    # Increment the split number
    i += 1
```

Comment: `df.repartition(4).write.csv(...)`

Comment: this code gives me same "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted." error as I get when trying to export whole DF to CSV. I need some workaround to go easy on memory i.e. step by step as I was able to only export 10% of DF at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

`var dataFile = “path/to/folder“   df.repartition(4).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").format("csv").save(dataFile)`

I'm not sure about a local instance but hadoop/mapreduce is designed to output a partition for each reduce task. Where you're only running on a single node the repart might be a little memory intensive which normally gives you the **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted** error.